# WSO2 EMM shutdown hook triggred

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I had successffully installed WSO2 EMM on Linux with JDK 7.

The application works fine but the server shut down. In the logs files I found the following information:

```
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,044]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutdown hook triggered....
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,045]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Mobile Platform...
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,047]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Starting to switch to maintenance mode...
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,047]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Stopped all transport listeners
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,047]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for request service completion...
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,051]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All requests have been served.
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,051]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for deployment completion...
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,057]  INFO {org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext} - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 09 09:59:43 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-10-09 10:03:18,058]  INFO {org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory} -  Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@24350e35:defining beans .....
```

Here is the log above with only the messages:

```
Shutdown hook triggered....
Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Mobile Platform...
Starting to switch to maintenance mode...
Stopped all transport listeners
Waiting for request service completion...
All requests have been served.
Waiting for deployment completion...
Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 09 09:59:43 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@24350e35:defining beans .....
```

How can we disable shut down trigger of carbon server? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Amal, could you please let us know more details including, whether this is happening followed by any specific action? Do you have any custom configurations or is this just a fresh pack? What is the EMM version that you are using? etc.

Comment: This happened to us also. Any update son this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a Kubernetes environment, I found that it was the `livenessProbe`/`readinessProbe` that were restarting the containers. You can see this by looking at the events for the Pod, though you will only see a single message about the failed health check (not one per restart, as one might expect). Increasing the `initialDelaySeconds` fixed this for me.